# Excel VBA coding for creating a new table based on already existing table

Tags: excel, vba

Shown below is how my table is currently organized as:

[image: current]

I have hidden other columns that I'm not interested in. The first 12 rows represent a single 5vs5 game. The first 5 rows are 5 players in team A, and the next 5 are the other 5 players in team B. The result column indicates win(1)  or loss(0). The 11th and 12th rows represent "Team" statistics, which I'm not interested in.

I would like to reformat this and create a new table, in which a single row represents a single game, not individual players.

The desired outcome would look like this:

[image: desired]

Any input in writing vba code for this is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you tell game 1 from 2 apart? Or are the teams always 5 people? Are the team stats always present after all members are listed?

Comment: Do you have any code to share? Sounds like you need a loop

Comment: Yes, teams are always made of 5 players. Each game is consisted of total 10 players. Yes, the team stats are always present after all members are listed. I can tell game 1 from 2 apart because the first 12 rows indicate game 1 data, the next 12 rows indicate game 2 data, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your headers (in my example they are on columns `E:G`) and then the macro will fill in the values for `gameid, won, lose`. Note this assumes a fresh start each time. i.e. you cannot run the macro, add new data to the source table, and then re-run the macro. If you do, you will have duplicates and your gameids will be off. Therefore, your output table must start out blank each time.

This also assumes:

1. Your raw data **has a header** (i.e. data starts at row 2)
2. Each games data spans **12 rows and only 12 rows**
3. Each game **only consists of 10 players** and the players are represented in the **first 10 rows** for each game.

   *The last 2 rows for each game are ignored in this macro*

---

```
Sub Try()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, i As Long, x As Long, y As Long
Dim Winners As String, Losers As String


lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2
y = 2


'Loop the 12 records for each game    
For i = 1 To lr Step 12
    
    'Loop 10 records for players & assign winners/losers
    For x = 1 To 10
        If ws.Range("C" & x + i) = 1 Then
            Winners = Winners & ", " & ws.Range("B" & x + i)
        ElseIf ws.Range("C" & x + i) = 0 Then
            Losers = Losers & ", " & ws.Range("B" & x + i)
        End If
    Next x
    
    'Output strings
    ws.Range("E" & y) = y
    ws.Range("F" & y) = Mid(Winners, 3)
    ws.Range("G" & y) = Mid(Losers, 3)
    
    'Reset strings for next game
    y = y + 1
    Winners = ""
    Losers = ""
    
Next i


End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works exactly how I wanted. I made a small fix though: "ws.Range("E" & y) = y" should be "ws.Range("E" & y) = y - 1" to correctly compute the gameId starting from 1 instead of 2. First time actually inquiring something on stackoverflow and I am amazed. Thanks urdearboy.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using `Power Query` (aka `Get&Transform`) available in Excel 2010+

- Filter out the team statistics
- Create a column which generates a game number
- Group by Game number and extract the winners and losers depending on the Results content

**M Code**

*note: code simplified*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="gameTbl"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"playerid", Int64.Type},{"champion", type text}, {"result", Int64.Type}
        }),

//Filter at the Team statistics
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([champion] <> null)),

//Generate Game number
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Game Number", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], 10), Int64.Type),

//Remove unneeded Index column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division",{"Index"}),

//Group by Game and extract the relevant data by filtering each subTable in the grouping
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Game Number"}, {
        {"Winning Champs", each Table.SelectRows(_, each ([result] = 1))[champion] },
        {"Losing Champs", each Table.SelectRows(_, each ([result] = 0))[champion]}
        }),

//Convert list to comma separated values
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {"Winning Champs", each 
            Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Extracted Values1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Values", {"Losing Champs", 
            each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values1"
```

[image]

[image]

To generate the above,

- select some cell in your data table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range'
- After the PQ Editor opens

  - Navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
  - Note the table name in Line 2 of the code
  - Paste the M-code in place of what you see
  - In Line 2, replace the table name with the one originally generated
  - Examine the code, comments, and also navigate through the Applied Steps

Comment: I need to learn power query. So powerful and my biggest gap in excel know-how. Kudos

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of using an array.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR(), vWin(), vLoss()
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, m As Integer
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1) 'data sheet
    Set toWs = Sheets(2) 'result sheet
    
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    
    ReDim vR(1 To (r - 1) / 12, 1 To 3)
    
    For i = 2 To r Step 12
        n = n + 1
        ReDim vWin(1 To 5): ReDim vLoss(1 To 5)
        k = 0: m = 0
        For j = 0 To 9
            If vDB(i + j, 3) = 1 Then
                k = k + 1
                vWin(k) = vDB(i + j, 2)
            Else
                m = m + 1
                vLoss(m) = vDB(i + j, 2)
            End If
        Next j
        vR(n, 1) = n
        vR(n, 2) = Join(vWin, ",")
        vR(n, 3) = Join(vLoss, ",")
    Next i
    With toWs
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Range("a1").Resize(1, 3) = Array("gameid", "winnigchamps", "losingchamps")
        .Range("a2").Resize(n, 3) = vR
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you have access to the new excel array formulas `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` you can do this without VBA**

1. Add a column to your raw data to assign `GameID`. You can do this manually or use `=CEILING.MATH((ROW(B2)-1)/12,1)` starting on the second row and drag down
2. Output the `UNIQUE` game IDs in `F2`
3. Output the winners in `G2` and drag formula down
4. Output the losers in `H2` and drag formula down

---

Here is a screenshot of the table + formulas needed which are all highlighted yellow

[image]

[image]

---